# Retrieve current translation domain in Twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Is it possible to retrieve current default translation domain inside twig template? I've dug through Symfony\Bridge\Twig translation elements, but after I got into TranslationDefaultDomainNodeVisitor, I got lost. There are no global variables set by translator inside twig. For example, in form component extension it's as trivial as using {{ translation_domain }} (which can be overwritten from FormType).

Comment: I'm not very experienced using twig, but from my understanding wouldn't the best way to do this be to find this information in the application layer and then pass that information manually as a parameter to whatever template you render.